# Error caused by bad sql grammar, but it works perfect in database

Tags: java, sql, spring

I have this piece of SQL code in my method in a repository. It is to find the total price of items, based on the given id's. This price should be returning a BigDecimel total price, but it gives me an error bad SQL grammar. When I put this SQL in my MariaDB (phpMyAdmin), it works perfect. Why is this not working?

I am using this in Java Spring repository.

```java
@Override
public BigDecimal vindTotalePrijsByIds(Set<Long> ids) {
    var sql = "select sum(prijs) from films where id in (" +
            "?,".repeat(ids.size()-1) +
            "?)";
    return template.queryForObject(sql, BigDecimal.class, ids);
}
```

These are the columns: (there is no issue with the database, works perfect on all other statements). But so you can see I'm taking the right values.

id |genreId | titel | voorraad | gereserveerd|prijs

I get this error.

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
> PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select sum(prijs) from
> films where id in (?,?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
> No value specified for parameter 2

What is wrong with my SQL statement?
To answer to the question to verify that is has two. Yes, i ran it with a test(the formule to find the id's works):

```
    @Test
    void findtotaleprijsbyids() {
        long idEen = idVanTestFilm();
        long idTwee = idVanTestFilmTwee();
        assertThat(filmRepository.vindTotalePrijsByIds(Set.of(idTwee, idEen))).isEqualByComparingTo(BigDecimal.TEN);
    }
```

with this in my database inserted, insertFilm.sql
(you can assume my test does everything correct)

```
insert into films (genreId, titel, voorraad, gereserveerd, prijs) values (8, 'testFilm', 5, 0, 5.00),
                                                                         (8, 'testFilmTwee', 5, 0, 5.00);
```

So I know it has 2 parameters. But so maybe I execute wrong. Looking in that direction now.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your SQL statement itself, there is something wrong with how you execute it. The `Set`  `ids` is taken as a single parameter. `JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(String, Class<?>, Object...)`: the last is a varargs, so you need to convert the set to an array.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the method called is [`queryForObject(String query, Class<T> requiredType, Object... args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-). Hence, the `Set<Long>` is interpreted as a single parameter, not as multiple parameters. If we want to transform the `Set` into an array, we can call [`Set::toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#toArray()):

```
return template.queryForObject(sql, BigDecimal.class, ids.toArray());
```